# Cannot scroll tab content in Tabhost derived activity

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have created the Tab Layout example found on the Android Developers site [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) in Android 2.2. While the example works as advertised I can not scroll at all on the text views that I have placed in one of the activities. The TextView objects were created dynamically in the given activity if that matters. I have tried wrapping the different portions of the components in main.xml with ScrollView but I either get a build error or a Force Close on launch. Attached is the code that implements the textViews and it's xml as well as main.xml file. I cannot post images since I am new. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
    <LinearLayout        
        android:orientation="vertical"                
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:padding="5dp"> 

        <TabWidget            
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />      
        <FrameLayout            
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />             
     <!--         android:padding="5dp" --> 
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Source that creates my TextViews in the Tab:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        DisplayTexts(20);
    }

    private void DisplayTexts(int length){
        if(length == 0)
            return;

    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);         
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        registerForContextMenu(tv);
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        tv.setText("TextView " + String.valueOf(i));
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(tv);
        tv.setId(i);
    }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    this.addContentView(layout, layoutParam);
}
```

xml file for above activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with this xml for your activity:

**activity2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_content">
        <LinearLayout                  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And then try adding component in Activity2.class like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
...
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        registerForContextMenu(tv);
        tv.setTextSize(30);
        tv.setText("TextView " + String.valueOf(i));
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setId(i);
        layout.addView(tv);        
}
...
```

Comment: Made the suggested changes and I can now scroll. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help.You should accept the answer if it helped you,by checking the green "correct" mark on top left side of the answer.It helps you improve your accept ratio and also for others reference to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addContentView, use SetContentView and try setting canScrollVertically (int direction) for the layout.

A listView could be an alternative for what you are trying to accomplish.